# YouTube embed and PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api

I allowed the user to upload a YouTube embed link that will display the video on their profile page. However, as my current code runs, it does not work. I echoed the field successfully from the database that holds the youtube embed link so I know the php code is working in terms of extracting the link. I then replace the PHP code and put the actual link in the src attribute but it still does not work. Here is the code below.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
    src="<?php echo $detailed_profile_data['video_1'];?>" 
    frameborder="1" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

The function detailed_profile_data grabs the link the user submitted to the database.This is what it returns. youtu.be/yWk7FOnFvGs

Comment: What's actually at `$detailed_profile_data['video_1']`? Perhaps you can share a sample data.

Comment: As @uzyn said, need to know what is being output in `src`

Comment: have you check $detailed_profile_data['video_1'], is giving you a proper value???

Comment: The function detailed_profile_data grabs the link the user submitted to the database.This is what it returns.                         http://youtu.be/yWk7FOnFvGs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use oEmbed to find out the actual embeddable URL from the URL that user submits.

This Stack Overflow article might help: [How can I retrieve YouTube video details from video URL using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896233/how-can-i-retrieve-youtube-video-details-from-video-url-using-php)