# Retrieve YouTube video details, including description from video URL using PHP?

Tags: php, youtube-api

After searching stackoverflow, I've found: [How can I retrieve YouTube video details from video URL using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896233/how-can-i-retrieve-youtube-video-details-from-video-url-using-php)

using the following code (I have changed to https instead of http and also added $_GET['v'] for getting video code from browser URL):

```
function get_youtube($url) {

 $youtube = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=". $url ."&format=json";

 $curl = curl_init($youtube);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $return = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return json_decode($return, true);

}

$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $_GET['v'];

// Display Data 
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_youtube($url));
echo '</pre>';
```

I was able to get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [thumbnail_url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AhN5MbTJ0pk/hqdefault.jpg
    [version] => 1.0
    [type] => video
    [html] => <iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AhN5MbTJ0pk?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    [provider_url] => https://www.youtube.com/
    [thumbnail_width] => 480
    [width] => 480
    [thumbnail_height] => 360
    [author_url] => https://www.youtube.com/user/AndreasChoice
    [author_name] => AndreasChoice
    [title] => GROSS SMOOTHIE CHALLENGE! ft. Tealaxx2
    [height] => 270
    [provider_name] => YouTube
)
```

Which is great, but I also need to retrieve the full 'description' of the video that is missing. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the [API specification](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)?

Comment: Yes. But that didn't help, it's all greek to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to receive the description of a video you have 2 options.

1. Use an API.
2. Crawl the website.

The API that you need is under `googleapis.com` domain.

The url that you need to use is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY&fields=items(id,snippet(description))&part=snippet
```

Notice that you have to change the `VIDEO_ID` and `YOUR_API_KEY`.

 To get an API key follow these instructions: [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#before-you-start).

---

Building a web crawler is more complex.
Try following this tutorial to build your own web crawler [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-basic-web-crawler-pull-information-website/)

Comment: Thank you! That's is exactly what I was looking for.