# HTML5 Video - Get final src URL destination

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm displaying video content from a 3rd party service on my website:

```
<video src="http://www.example.com/api/v1/media/video.mp4?status=true"></video>
```

The service detects the user's geo-location and browser's language and returns video that fit those parameters.

```
http://www.example.com/api/v1/media/video.mp4?status=true REDIRECT TO http://www.example.com/api/v1/media/US/EN/English_CAT.mp4
```

Other than the media URL, the service doesn't provide the actual file name that particular user received.

How can I fetch the final media path/name? Tried multiple ways but iframes blocked by X-Frame-Options: DENY and AJAX blocked as well.

Comment: Do you want to do operations on iframe html? which is third party url or website?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand what you wrote but: as I wrote I tried to use the url in iframe but it blocked by x-frames option. As for the second part of your question, the URL is 3rd party to my website domain.

Comment: I don't exact requirement, But I can tell about CasperJS / PhantomJS to achieve this, but you need to study this.

Comment: Youtube provides details about their videos, see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896233/how-can-i-retrieve-youtube-video-details-from-video-url-using-php. Not sure that applies to your case though, you might be forced to download the .mp4 in the backend, get its metadata and send them to your client code.

Comment: @AnupYadav I'm familiar with headless webkits for server side but it will not do much in my case as each user receive different video file.

Comment: @PhilippeSultan It's not a Youtube video. On top of that, forcing the download on the backend will result in the same video file for everyone like the other dude's suggestion above

Comment: Doesn't really matter about dynamic video file, you can still achieve that using CasperJS then

Comment: What exactly is this 3rd party service? I have yet to see 2 APis where the differences between them are minor. Need to know what this service is, there's no generic solution when it's a problem like this.

Comment: The name of the development company is "MarkPulse"; there is no public documentation.

Comment: Just curious, how is AJAX blocked? Have you tried setting all the same headers on your request? What happens if you resend the same request?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is you probably can't do this all on the client-side. You will run into [`same-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) issues. In addition, it is not possible to directly get the HTTP headers of a `<video>` element.

If the service provider for the videos enables [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) support you may be able to get the final URL via a workaround. Even with `CORS` enabled you won't be able to get the HTTP headers or final URL of the video from the `<video>` element.

You can work around this by:

1. Make a 2nd HTTP request (`XMLHttpRequest`, [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), `$.ajax`, etc) to the same URL.
2. Make a [`HEAD`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) request instead of a `GET` request. `GET` requests will attempt to retrieve the entire file. `HEAD` requests do not download the body, only the headers, which would be enough for resolving the redirect.
3. Look in the headers of the HEAD response for the final URL path.

Here is an example that uses [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
var request = new Request(yourVideoUrl);
request.mode = 'cors';
request.method = 'HEAD';

fetch(request)
.then(function(res){
  console.log(res.url); // This should be the final URL
});
```

Comment: Good catch. Fixed the typo.