# How to display youtube video data details after pasting url in textarea using html and jquery, exactly like whatsapp does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

How to display youtube video data details after pasting url in textarea using html and jquery, exactly like whatsapp does?

Comment: The question asked is too broad. It doesn't specify whether you want to display data in the textarea or you want to get the data.
If you want to fetch the data, use 

  [Youtube Data Api:](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/youtube_actionscript3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the video's metadata using the oEmbed Interface. [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896233/how-can-i-retrieve-youtube-video-details-from-video-url-using-php) for more info about that.

Now here the problem with that interface, YouTube doesn't have a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header present which makes it tough for other web services to make requests to it. Your browser will block any http requests you try to make to YouTube

There's two ways we can deal with this:

The first is creating a sort of wrapper around the oembed interface. You create some endpoint using your backend service which make the actual http request to Youtube, then your application makes ajax requests to that endpoint. Check out the answer I linked above to get an idea of how to set that up

The second way is the dirty way. We'll make use of a proxy service called [CorsAnywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) which deals with the problem we were discussing earlier.

So first here's the markup we're going to need to lay everything out

```
<div class="application">
  <div class="video-meta">
      <img id="video-thumbnail">
    <a id="video-link"><h4 id="video-title"></h4></a>
  </div>
  <textarea id="link" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
```

And some styling for the markup

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%
}

#video-thumbnail {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

#video-link {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.video-meta {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 150ms ease;
}

.video-meta.open {
  height: 150px;
}

.application {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.video-meta {
  width: 100%;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Lastly the JS that will be making driving the whole thing

```
    // Prefilter to auto-magically prepend cors anywhere domain to 
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
    if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
        options.url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
      // Host local instance maybe?
    }
});

// Function that will retrieve the data for a particular video
function getVideoData(url) {
      var base = 'https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url={link}&format=json';

     var link = base.replace('{link}', url);
     var result = null;

      $.ajax({
          url: link,
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false, // Probably not the best thing. Just for demo purposes.
          success: function(data) {
              result = data;
          } 
       });

     return result;
}

// Event handler for keyup event
$('#link').on('keyup', function() {
   $('.video-meta').removeClass('open');
   var link = $(this).val();

  // Check URL's maybe

   var data = getVideoData(link);

  // Check if we go valid response
    if(!data) {
      alert("Something went wrong");
      return;
    }

    // Set values
    $('#video-thumbnail').attr('src', data.thumbnail_url);
    $('#video-link').attr('href', link);
    $('#video-title').text(data.title);

    $('.video-meta').addClass('open');
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/705585/). Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for your answer. highly appreciated.