# YouTube API: detect that the video is age-restricted

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As per [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos):

> `contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating`
>
> A rating that YouTube uses to identify age-restricted content.

But that doesn't seem to work as documented, here's the example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUc0wyae-WI

API response:

```js
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "U9x_WdDwATA",
      "contentDetails": {
        "contentRating": {},
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that `contentRating.ytRating` isn't set which means that the video doesn't have age-restriction according to API.

But actually it's not the case: https://www.youtube.com/embed/IUc0wyae-WI?hl=en

> This video is age-restricted and only available on YouTube. Learn more
> Watch on YouTube

Where's my mistake? Or is it the bug in YouTube API v3?

Comment: That video plays well on YouTube's site. You may try to report this to Google (through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/)); the company's staff could well shed more light on this issue.

Comment: @stvar According to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support StackOverflow is the right place to report to Google :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how things are in reality. SO is not a subsidiary of Google. More than that, if you go back for say the last couple of years of SO entries pertaining to the tags [tag:youtube-api] and [tag:youtube-data-api], you'll see that there's no SO user that assumes publicly to answer questions in Google's name. Indeed, official accounts on issues as your is can only be obtained through the official issue tracker of that company.

Comment: Also have to add that the video plays well on YouTube only after signing in (thus upon confirming the user's age). The issue you had raised looks well like a bug indeed.

Comment: @LimonMonte: Issue Tracker: Something wrong? Send us a **bug report!** - it is shown at the [end of the YouTube Data API webpage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).

Comment: Reported here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179172834 thank you @MauricioAriasOlave

Comment: @Limon Monte: your post on the issue tracker has issues: [according to the official specification](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating), the expected value of the property `contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating` is not the *JSON object* `{"ytAgeRestricted":true}` but the *JSON string* `"ytAgeRestricted"` instead.

Comment: Right, commented that in the issue, thank you @stvar

Answer (score 1):

try to find playabilityStatus:

[image]

see for more details:
[Use the YouTube API to check if a video is embeddable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60935120/use-the-youtube-api-to-check-if-a-video-is-embeddable)

> This is undocumented API existing for long time, so exploring it is up
> to developer. I am aware of "status" (ok/fail), "errorcode" (100 and
> 150 in my practice), "reason" (string description of error). I am
> getting duration ("length_seconds") this way because oEmbed does not
> provide this information (strange, but true) and I can hardly motivate
> every employer to get keys from youTube to use official API

Comment: This workaround will do the work, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work and returns a lot of false positives. Example: https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=CJinWua98NA returns UNPLAYABLE but the video is actually playable.